Add_filter just custom page types
I have this add_filter function in functions.php:
function auto_link_post_titles( $content ) {
    // This is to get all published posts from all post types.
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'any', // this is to get posts from all post types.
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // this is to retrieve all posts
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    // Here are looping through each post and replace the title in the content with a link.
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $post_title = esc_html( $post->post_title ); // Here we are getting the post title.
        $post_link  = esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); // Here we are getting the post link.
        
        // Create a link element
        $link = '<a href="' . $post_link . '" target="_blank">' . $post_title . '</a>';
        
        // Here we are replacing the plain text title with the link.
        $content = str_replace( $post_title, $link, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// We have apply the function to the content of posts.
add_filter( 'acf/load_value', 'auto_link_post_titles' );

I want to apply this only to certain post types.
It's possible? And if yes, how?
Thanks.

Please edit your question to provide more information. Especially helpful would be seeing the auto_link_post_titles() function.

Done, edited, I added

You're using 'post_type' => 'any' in your get_post() arguments, which will get, well, any post type. Instead, specify which post type(s) you want to retrieve.
function auto_link_post_titles( $content ) {
    // Sets the post type(s) we'll retrieve.
    $desired_post_types = array( 'my_post_type', 'my_other_post_type' );
    // This is to get all published posts from all post types.
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => $desired_post_types,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // this is to retrieve all posts
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    // Here are looping through each post and replace the title in the content with a link.
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $post_title = esc_html( $post->post_title ); // Here we are getting the post title.
        $post_link  = esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); // Here we are getting the post link.
        
        // Create a link element
        $link = '<a href="' . $post_link . '" target="_blank">' . $post_title . '</a>';
        
        // Here we are replacing the plain text title with the link.
        $content = str_replace( $post_title, $link, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// We have apply the function to the content of posts.
add_filter( 'acf/load_value', 'auto_link_post_titles' );

Replace array( 'my_post_type', 'my_other_post_type' ) with the post types you want to select.

Works fine! Thanks!
